# My custom prompt doesn't get updated after I hit enter?

Tags: linux, bash, command-prompt, ps1

I'm trying to make a custom prompt. When I hit enter certain values in the prompt should be updated, but its not getting updated.
I tried adding export, like this

```
export PS1="[$v0][$v1][$v2][$v3]$"
```

But doesnt get updated. For example in the console i write 0 2 "date -R", the
output would be something like this

```
[Fri, 28 Aug 2020 16:54:00 +0200][][][]$
```

When i press enter it stays exactly the same, but i want it to be updated.
I tried also doing single quotes at the PS1 instead of double quotes, but didn't work.

Heres the full code:

```
#!/bin/bash

updatedata() {



v=$(awk -v strSearch="$1" '
BEGIN{
    FS=";"
}
{
    gsub(/\r/,"")
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i==strSearch){ print i
            exit
        }
    }
}
' data.csv)

sum=0
for x in `cut -f $v -d ';' data.csv`
do
    x="${x/$'\r'/}"
    let sum=$sum+$x
done

if [ $pos -eq 0 ]
then
    v0=$sum
elif [ $pos -eq 1 ]
then
    v1=$sum
elif [ $pos -eq 2 ]
then
    v2=$sum
elif [ $pos -eq 3 ]
then
    v3=$sum
fi




         
}
           

       
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    pos=$1
    typevar=$2
    stringvar=$3
    case $pos in
      0) v0=$3 ;;
      1) v1=$3 ;;
      2) v2=$3 ;;
      3) v3=$3 ;;
      *) echo "One of the values has invalid position entered, try again"
     
    esac
    case $typevar in
      1) if [  $pos -eq 0 ]
        then
            if [ "$stringvar" != "null" ]
            then
                v0=$stringvar
            else
                v0=""
            fi
        elif [ $pos -eq 1 ]
        then
            if [ "$stringvar" != "null" ]
            then
                v1=$stringvar
            else
                v1=""
            fi
        elif [ $pos -eq 2 ]
        then
            if [ "$stringvar" != "null" ]
            then
                v2=$stringvar
            else
                v2=""
            fi
        elif [ $pos -eq 3 ]
        then
            if [ "$stringvar" != "null" ]
            then
                v3=$stringvar
            else
                v3=""
            fi
        fi ;;
           
       
      2) if [ $pos -eq 0 ]
        then
            v0=`eval $3`
        elif [ $pos -eq 1 ]
        then
            v1=`eval $3`
        elif [ $pos -eq 2 ]
        then
            v2=`eval $3`
        elif [ $pos -eq 3 ]
        then
            v3=`eval $3`
        fi ;;
      3) updatedata $3 ;;
      *) echo "Invalid type of variable, try again"
     
     
     
    esac
    shift
    shift
    shift
   
done

export PS1="[$v0][$v1][$v2][$v3]$"
```

Comment: You need to put the value in single quotes. Otherwise the variables are expanded when you assign the variable, not when the prompt is displayed.

Comment: so you mean like this? export PS1="['$v0']"

Comment: What do you mean by `I write 0 2 "date -R"`? How does that get into the `v0`, `v1`, etc. variables?

Comment: 0 stands for position of brackets, 2 stands for the type of the input (type 1 is string type 2 is a command(which i use now) and type 3 is a csv column) and the last part is basically whatever you want to input in the brackets, for example "date -R"

Comment: And how does that get into the variables that you're using in the prompt?

Comment: If you enter `0 2 "date -R"`, the shell will try to execute the command `0` with arguments `2` and `date -R`.  Have you implemented a command named `0` that populates the variables you are referencing in PS1?

Comment: Maybe its better if I show the full code? I edited my post

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610384/why-cant-i-use-in-ps1-instead-of-backticks) for some ideas that may help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the prompt in single quotes, not double quotes. Variables inside double quotes are evaluated when you assign to `PS1`, not when the prompt is printed.

```
export PS1='[$v0][$v1][$v2][$v3]$'
```

You can also put command substitutions directly into the prompt, you don't need variables.

```
export PS1='[$(date -R)][$v1][$v2][$v3]$'
```

Comment: I tested it, it worked for me. I did `v0=foo` and my prompt changed to `[foo][][][]$`

Comment: That does work, but I mean for example certain commands will change overtime like for example the date -R. Time changes every second. But when I press enter the time stays the same

Comment: Look at the second version in my answer. That will use the current time.

Comment: Yes but how about when I want to use a different position? It needs to depend on number of position that i wrote in command line. So for example I want it in the 3rd bracket, that wont work

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. There's nothing that automatically puts what you typed into the prompt. You need to reassign the variables.

Comment: If you want to change the third bracket, do `v2=something`

Comment: It also doesn't work recursively. You can't put an expression in `v2` and get it to re-evaluate that every time the prompt is shown. If you want it to be evaluated, it needs to be in the `PS1` variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` is probably a terrible idea, and you can do this without it, but one idea to get you started:

```
$ PS1='[$v0][$v1][$v2][$v3]\$ '
[][][][]$ v2=test
[][][test][]$ setps() { eval v$1="'$2'"; }
[][][test][]$ setps 2 "$(date)"
[][][Fri Aug 28 15:44:21 GMT 2020][]$
```